# How to convert multiple defferent correlation matrix in dataframe by pairs in one time?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to convert the multiple correlation matrix into dataframe at the same time

my matrix group like this:
    [[image]

the output I want like this:
    [image]

my current code is like this:

```
dat1 <- read.xlsx("correlation reshape.xlsx",sheet=1,rows=1:7,cols=2:8)#read studyid1-James2005
dat1
reshape_1<-as_cordf(dat1)#reshape the data into matrix
reshape_1
long.format1<-reshape_1 %>% gather(-rowname, key = "colname", value = "cor")#reshape the data into 
na1<-na.omit(long.format1)#omit NA value
## psychmeta
dat2 <- read.xlsx("correlation reshape.xlsx", sheet=1,rows=8:11,cols=2:5,skipEmptyCols=TRUE)#read studyid2-Ashforth2010
reshape_2<-as_cordf(dat2)
long.format2<-reshape_2 %>% gather(-rowname, key = "colname", value = "cor")
long.format2
na2<-na.omit(long.format2)
#output method1 
c <- rbind(na1,na2)#combine na1,na2..., and put them out.
write.table(c,"reshape_output.csv",sep=",")
```

my current method is to sperate the two correlation matrix, but i will have more than 1000 different correlation matrix, i want to know how to process them at the same time into the dataframe by pairs  and add the ID as the first column? pls help

Comment: you need to provide data instead of an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to reshape your data:
So, first let's define two correlations dataframes (I used `mtcars` and `iris`)

```r
df = mtcars[c(1:10),]
table1 = cor(df)
ID = rep("Table1",nrow(table1))
table1 = data.frame(cbind(ID,rownames(table1),table1))
```

Here, you can see the structure of df1:

```r
> head(table1[c(1:3),c(1:5)])
         ID   V2                mpg                cyl               disp
mpg  Table1  mpg                  1 -0.861416514957246 -0.773986849952057
cyl  Table1  cyl -0.861416514957246                  1  0.888289505678108
disp Table1 disp -0.773986849952057  0.888289505678108                  1
```

Now, we are defining a table2

```r
df2 = iris[c(1:20),-5]
table2 = cor(df2)
ID = rep("Table2",nrow(table2))
table2 = data.frame(cbind(ID,rownames(table2),table2))
```

With the following structure:

```r
> table2
                 ID           V2      Sepal.Length       Sepal.Width      Petal.Length       Petal.Width
Sepal.Length Table2 Sepal.Length                 1 0.875633706307696 0.316760894337443 0.561846414596048
Sepal.Width  Table2  Sepal.Width 0.875633706307696                 1 0.260051160822913 0.753193903742604
Petal.Length Table2 Petal.Length 0.316760894337443 0.260051160822913                 1 0.368645505390148
Petal.Width  Table2  Petal.Width 0.561846414596048 0.753193903742604 0.368645505390148                 1
```

Now, we are going to reshape both of them using `pivot_longer` and we will be able to associate together using `rbind`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

table2 = table2 %>% pivot_longer(., cols = 3:ncol(.),names_to = "Rownames",values_to = "Correlation")
table1 = table1 %>% pivot_longer(., cols = 3:ncol(.),names_to = "Rownames",values_to = "Correlation")
table_final = rbind(table1,table2)
```

And here the output, you can have:

```r
> head(table_final)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID     V2    Rownames Correlation       
  <fct>  <fct> <chr>    <fct>             
1 Table1 mpg   mpg      1                 
2 Table1 mpg   cyl      -0.861416514957246
3 Table1 mpg   disp     -0.773986849952057
4 Table1 mpg   hp       -0.893722265184114
5 Table1 mpg   drat     0.541358491575314 
6 Table1 mpg   wt       -0.599189365369649
```

Does it answer your question ?

**EDIT: Using `for` loop to process multiple correlation matrix**

From what I understand from your question and your comments, you have in one excel file multiple correlation matrix each of them identify by their `studyID`. Am I right ?

To process all them, you can use a `for` loop like this one (assuming that your excel file is named `test_xl`) :

```r
library(openxlsx)
test = read.xlsx("../test_xl.xlsx")
uniqueID = unique(test$studyID)[!is.na(unique(test$studyID))]
table_final = NULL
for(i in 1:length(uniqueID))
{
  df = test[which(test$studyID == uniqueID[i]),]
  df = df[colSums(!is.na(df))>0]
  if(i == 1){colnames(df) = colnames(test)[1:ncol(df)]}
  else{
    colnames(df)[3:ncol(df)] <- test[min(grep(uniqueID[i],test$studyID))-1,3:ncol(df)]
  }


  df = df %>% pivot_longer(., cols = 3:ncol(df), names_to = 'Colnames', values_to = 'correlation')
  if(i == 1){table_final = df}
  else{table_final = rbind(table_final,df)}
}
```

Hopefully, it will work for you

Comment: Thanks so much, I understand your method, you create two table for two different correlation matrix based on the ID, but if i have  more than 100 or even more than 1000 ID, it may hard to create more than 1000 tables then combine, so i am wondering is there any other way to do this, like some if condition to judge?

Comment: The two different correlation matrix that I created were just for the example. If you have 100 or 1000 different dataframe, the process will be the same (the part with `pivot_longer` ..). You just have to integrate it in a `for` loop. It also depends the kind of data you are starting with. Is it raw dataframe ? or matrix correlation ? How are defined your ID ?

Comment: This is matrix correlation, the ID is different type of correlation based on the different study, Thanks for the help, I try to figure out it

Comment: @keavy, so, if I understand well, you have one excel file filled with multiple correlation matrix, am I right ? I edited my code to introduce the processing of excel file in the loop

Comment: @keavy, I corrected few errors in my `for` loop code, in case you want to test it on your dataset

Comment: Yes!! that is what i want,and sorry for the unconvience, i should provide the data directly instead of image, thanks so much!!!